# Which DAW, when rewired with Record / Reason, is better on system performance?

Tags: daw, plugins, performance

In general, I try to stick to Propellerhead Record / Reason to produce music. But now that I am investing in more natural-sounding external Sound Sample libraries (namely NI's Session Strings Pro and Modart's Pianoteq 3), it becomes trickier to integrate.

Managing all the MIDI clips and automation in one place is one challenge, but playing everything together without a dramatic performance drop (and hear clipping problems) IS a huge deal.

I've tried Record & Ableton Live so far. Live shown me today that it was pushing my CPU around 80-90% usage.

I'll admit, yes I'm doing my productions on a MacBook Pro. So I'm wondering...

Is there any better DAW hosts out there that could be more "gentle" and CPU friendly for projects that rewires Record & Reason into it?

Sub-question: Since my system is 64-bit, should I only consider DAWs & Plugins that are as well?

Answer (score 3):

I have had pretty good luck with [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/index.php) on my old single processor PC (Reaper also works on the Mac).

I haven't done anything with sampling, but even with my slow computer I have been able to play back several tracks with EQ and lots of effects on each channel without taxing the system much.  Reaper also has a [way to link to other computers](http://wiki.cockos.com/wiki/index.php/ReaMote) running reaper over a network and offload some of the processing.

It's free to try, and very inexpensive to buy if it works for you.

Comment: Hey @Friend Of George, Thanks for the recommendation! I've tried Reaper, and now have a discount license for it :D I was sold just 3 days using it :) It's got great performance and handling of resources.

Comment: Glad to hear it @bigp!